# Cloudformation iterate over function parameters

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I get the following error "Aws::CloudFormation::Errors::ValidationError Template error: variable names in Fn::Sub syntax must contain only alphanumeric characters, underscores, periods, and colons"

I think the problem is "${@:3}".

```
SfnRegistry.register(:test_script) do

<<-SCRIPT
#!/bin/bash -

function setup() { 
  # iterate over function parameters
  for id in ${@:3}
  do
    setup_project_rules $1 $id
  done 
}

SCRIPT

end
```

Comment: The error relates to the usage of `Fn::Sub` in a Cloudformation template. I think you are looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @MikeMiller The whole bash script is the value of  "Fn::Sub". In my CI pipeline I get the following relationship:  "Fn::Sub": "#!/bin/bash ..".